# Mootools Fx.Slide & CSS styles?

Tags: javascript, css, mootools, mootools-more, mootools-fx

I am playing around with Mootools' Fx.Slide effects for some drop down menus.  I've used them before with no issues, but for some reason now it seems as soon as I set up a new Fx.Slide on an element, it messes up my CSS styles.  Here's an uploaded example...

[Before applying Fx.Slide](http://aurorafxstudios.com/_rmc-menu/index.php?without=fxSlide)

[After applying Fx.Slide](http://aurorafxstudios.com/_rmc-menu/index.php?with=fxSlide)

You can see the difference in my drop down menu styles.  All my styles are applied first via [this style sheet](http://aurorafxstudios.com/_rmc-menu/styles/css/styles.css), and the line that seems to mess it up my styles is [line #19 in this menu.js script](http://aurorafxstudios.com/_rmc-menu/menu.js) (here is a [paste of the same thing, with line numbers.](http://paste2.org/CxEd3wV5)).

The difference between the two examples above is only [line #19 in menu.js](http://aurorafxstudios.com/_rmc-menu/menu.js), which you can see I've commented out in the first example...
`subNav[index] = new Fx.Slide(subNav[index], {duration: 200});`

Again, the weird thing is that I have used Fx.Slide on other websites (like the drop down menus [on this site](http://cefontario.org)), and it never seemed to mess up any of my styles.  Any advice?

Comment: Totally unrelated to the actual topic, but how is it possible that Sergio edited my original question here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because of how your styles are set up.

Fx.Slide adds a div around your `ul`. Therefore, your `ul` stops receiving its styles from `#header #nav > ul > li > ul` because it's no longer a direct descendant of `#header #nav > ul > li`.